# GoogleAuthUtil.getToken causing android app crash

Tags: java, android, authentication, android-asynctask, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to use GoogleAuthUtil.getToken to generate a token that I can use to sign into another service. When I attempt to use this method my app "hangs" and stops responding. Eventually my phone spits out some IO error messages.  I receive no result from the server.

The email address is my email address formatted as myname@gmail.com, I have used the server address for my scope, but right now I'm just trying to use the simplest strings possible just to get a result that I can start working with.

```
public  class GetTokens extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
 Context c;
 String TAG = "wnycmap issues";

public GetTokens(Context c) {
    this.c=c;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String...mEmail) {
    String token = "null";
    String mScope = "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me";
    String email = mEmail[0];
    System.out.println(c+email+mScope);
    try {
        token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                c,
                email,
                mScope);

        System.out.println(token);
    } catch (IOException transientEx) {
        // Network or server error, try later
        Log.e(TAG, transientEx.toString());
    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
        // Recover (with e.getIntent())
        Log.e(TAG, e.toString());
        // Intent recover = e.getIntent();
        //startActivityForResult(recover, REQUEST_CODE_TOKEN_AUTH);
    } catch (GoogleAuthException authEx) {
        Log.e(TAG, authEx.toString());
    }

    return token;
```

The Errors:

```
 E/SnepServer(32677): IO error
 E/SnepServer(32677): java.io.IOException
 E/SnepServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.dhimpl.NativeLlcpServiceSocket.accept(NativeLlcpServiceSocket.java:42)
 E/SnepServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.snep.SnepServer$ServerThread.run(SnepServer.java:213)
 D/NdefPushServer(32677): stop, thread = Thread[Thread-8152,5,main]
 D/NdefPushServer(32677): shuting down server thread
 E/HandoverServer(32677): IO error
 E/HandoverServer(32677): java.io.IOException
 E/HandoverServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.dhimpl.NativeLlcpServiceSocket.accept(NativeLlcpServiceSocket.java:42)
 E/HandoverServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.handover.HandoverServer$ServerThread.run(HandoverServer.java:108)
 E/NdefPushServer(32677): IO error
 E/NdefPushServer(32677): java.io.IOException
 E/NdefPushServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.dhimpl.NativeLlcpServiceSocket.accept(NativeLlcpServiceSocket.java:42)
 E/NdefPushServer(32677):   at com.android.nfc.ndefpush.NdefPushServer$ServerThread.run(NdefPushServer.java:154)
```

And the code that I'm using to call my AsyncTask

```
private void authenticate() {
      String accountEmail="asdf";
      String authToken = "null";
      AccountManager am = AccountManager.get(context);
      Account[] accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");

      if (accounts != null){
          Account account = accounts[0];
          accountEmail = account.name;

          System.out.println(context);
          try {
                authToken=new GetTokens(context).execute(accountEmail).get();
          } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
          } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
          } 
      }
}
```

Comment: On a side note I can't seem to catch these errors at all.  I just attempted to run my code with a catch (Exception e) and it still performed the same way.

Comment: I get the following warnings every time I attempt to use googleAuthUtil

Answer (score 1):

Try few things,

1. Put a catch for GooglePlayServicesAvailabilityException
2. Check if you have placed  correct meta-data in application element in AndroidManifest.xml
   `<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />`
3. Put a catch for RuntimeException as a last resort to dig the source of crash.